# symony apache htaccess how to lose the /public/ from route?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have symfony 6 and apache pack is installed. Nothing changes when I run recipes:update so I understand apache pack is updated (and has placed .htaccess files for me?).

The route to my site is still mydomain.com/public/

I want to lose the folder "public" from the route, obviously.

I'm on cloudways so I can't start changing the folder structure around or move the application part down a level from public_html and rename public_html to "public" (or the other way around, referencing the symfony public folder as oublic_html. It would break the otherwise seamless git deploy process.

I have managed this in the past, but I dont want to just find an htaccess file or rule that "seems to do the trick", I would like to find the correct way of doing it.

I've been looking in the symfony docs but haven't found how it's supposed to be handled. If it is in there, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Also, if there is such a thing as an apache pack, shouldn't that take care of this? Did I somehow fail in installing the apache pack perhaps?

The .htaccess file currently in my /public folder reads like this:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file in my root folder (public_html in the cloudways case) reads like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution..

Just put an .htaccess file in the web document root (in my case with cloudways it is called "public_html") with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Comment: Although this is the same as what you originally posted in the question? (This can, however, be simplified... see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76313905/369434).)

Answer (score 0):

> The `.htaccess` file in my root folder (public_html in the cloudways case) reads like this:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
> ```

Yes, this looks correct, however, it can be simplified. You are also missing the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` - not strictly necessary, but if you add any other directives in the future then it would be.

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.

Since you have the Symfony `.htaccess` file (front-controller pattern) in the `/public` subdirectory, you don't need the *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks that the request does not already start with `/public/`, since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited (by default), so there is no rewrite loop (which is what this condition is trying to avoid).

So, the following would suffice to rewrite all requests to the public subdirectory (essentially creating a "fake" document root):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```